# How to run in main thread from worker thread that start by Nancyfx? C#

Tags: c#, .net, multithreading, winforms, nancy

I have a problem with using nancyfx in my winform application (I make a winform app and use a nancyfx inside the application) So i can use some API url to make change in the winform without additional server or services (because i attached the nancy in the winform apps)

Here is my Form1.cs

```
public partial class Form1 : Form 
{

    public Form1(bool test)
    {
        InitializeComponent();

        textBox1.Text += "Apps Method "+ Environment.NewLine;

    }

    public bool startTestAPI()
    {
        textBox1.Text += "Api Worked" + Environment.NewLine);
    }

    private void button2_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        HostingAPI s = new HostingAPI();
        s.Start();
        textBox1.Text += "Api Running" + Environment.NewLine);
    }
}


public class ModuleCDM : NancyModule
{

    public ModuleCDM()
    {
        try
        {
            Thread th2 = Thread.CurrentThread;
            Get["/Start"] = parameters =>
            {

                Form1 form = new Form1(false);
                Thread testthread = Form1.curthread;

                bool res = form.startTestAPI();

                if (res == true)
                {
                    var feeds = new string[] { "Success" };
                    return Response.AsJson(feeds);
                }
                else
                {
                    var feeds = new string[] { "Failed" };
                    return Response.AsJson(feeds);
                }
            };
    }
}
}
```

and this is my HostingAPI.cs

```
public class HostingAPI
{
    private NancyHost hostNancy;

    private string hostUrl;

    public void Start()
    {
        hostUrl = ConfigModule.ModuleAddress;

        if (hostUrl == null) hostUrl = "http://localhost:5005";

        hostNancy = new NancyHost(new Uri(hostUrl));

        hostNancy.Start();

    }

    public void Stop()
    {
        hostNancy.Stop();
    }
}
```

And it successfully run without error, but when i call api (localhost:5005/Start) the textbox in winform apps not add the text i wanted ("Api Worked"). I noticed it is because Nancyfx create another thread when there is API call, and i can use invoke/begininvoke because !invokerequired always comes with value false. So how can i access the main thread or maybe another solution to update the UI when i call the API.

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have 2 issues in here.

1. You start host api service from *Form1* instance then within Nancy Module you create a different Form1 instance which is invisible and you try to do access certain methods within that class
2. Cross thread issue as you rightfully guessed . You are trying to write from  another thread context than the UI thread

Look at the code at below to achieve this. Bear in mind that you can create Singleton Form or find another way to access the instance of *Form1*

```
  public class HostingAPI

   {
        private NancyHost hostNancy;

        private string hostUrl;

        public HostingAPI()
        {
        }

        public void Start()
        {
            var hostConfig = new HostConfiguration
            {
                UrlReservations = new UrlReservations
                {
                    CreateAutomatically = true
                },
            };

            //hostUrl = ConfigModule.ModuleAddress;

            if (hostUrl == null) hostUrl = "http://localhost:5005";

            hostNancy = new NancyHost(hostConfig,new Uri(hostUrl));

            hostNancy.Start();

        }

        public void Stop()
        {
            hostNancy.Stop();
        }
    }

public partial class Form1 : Form
{
    delegate void SetTextCallback(string text);
    public static Form1 Instance;
    public Form1(bool test)
    {
        InitializeComponent();

        textBox1.Text += "Apps Method " + Environment.NewLine;
        Instance = this;

    }   

    private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        HostingAPI s = new HostingAPI();
        s.Start();
        textBox1.Text += "Api Running" + Environment.NewLine;
    }
    public void startTestAPI()
    {
        SetText("Api Worked" + Environment.NewLine);
    }

    private void SetText(string text)
    {
        if (this.textBox1.InvokeRequired)
        {
            SetTextCallback d = new SetTextCallback(SetText);
            this.Invoke(d, new object[] { text });
        }
        else
        {
            this.textBox1.Text += text;
        }
    }
}


 public class ModuleCDM : NancyModule
    {
        public ModuleCDM()
        {
            try
            {
                Thread th2 = Thread.CurrentThread;
                Get["/Start"] = parameters =>
                {
                    var form1 = Form1.Instance;
                    form1.startTestAPI();
                    var feeds = new[] {"Success"};
                    return Response.AsJson(feeds);
                };
            }
            catch
            {
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: Yay it works. i dont even think about the singleton form. Thanks a lot.